# Google Maps API v3: Passing an Image for symbolPath rather than a inbuilt symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I just got to know about the [Symbol Animation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate) offered by Google API.

Every thing is working fine in my code but I just want to know if I can pass a Image instead of a symbol in the below code.

```
var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: '#393'
 };
```

If yes, How can I do that? I've tried passing Image paths and Image objects. NOthing worked.. Please help me out.

Comment: See [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom)

Comment: Thank you for your help but what is it exactly written in Path? How do i decrypt this "M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly old post but I ran into it while trying to solve this problem, hopefully the info I've gathered will be of help.  @jlivni is correct that Symbol can't be replaced with an image.  The method to go about this is use Polyline and Marker.  You can replace the marker image with your custom one and have that move.

The nice thing about this method is you can use your new marker point to change the look of your polylines before/after your marker, see eta info from your marker to the end location, etc.

---

These are useful to look over but many of them use GMaps API v2:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
--especially:
----http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm (simple, just goes to destination)
----http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm (has a visible polyline trail behind it)
----http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip3.htm (rotates so it's always facing the road, this is what I wanted)

http://www.geocodezip.com/
----especially:
----http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html (this is API v3)
----http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html (also API v3 animates via xml not polyline)

---

Useful scripts:
v3_epoly.js taken from http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js.  The syntax in this file looks like it's straight up broken but the parts of it I've used work.  Probably want to go through this by hand to fix it up if you need it.
I also used Elabel3.js from a google group forum post (I think this is it https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel).  It's used for the marker animation.  It didn't work for me out of the box.  I had to make changes to onAdd(), draw() and redraw() for my program.  More info on that here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView

Comment: +1 It was definitely an old post but I was searching for an answer till now.. Finally you've given me a solid direction.. I'll definitely look into your bit-bucket for more of this. Thank you.! :) :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Keep in mind I'm still in the process of improving the code so I still have a lot of stuff either commented out that isn't needed, badly named variables/functions and there is some code that is in there that does nothing but hasn't broken anything so I haven't removed it yet.  I'm also making poor use of the methods in Elabel3.js (I have code in there I shouldn't and code outside of it that should be in there).  I also want to make improvements to the canvas rotation. `tl;dr I'm still actively working on this and it's probably worth keeping an eye on my repo for updates`

Answer (score 1):

No - Symbols are restricted to SVG paths, not arbitrary images.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an image url to the `google.maps.Icon` object, but the `google.maps.Symbol` object uses a `google.maps.SymbolPath` or SVG path. Look up SVG path syntax. It's a standard that many tools like CS and InkScape can produce for you.

See the official custom SymbolPath [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom) where SVG coords are supplied.